# How to display my output in a dropdown list

Tags: php, html

I want my program to list my data from mysql table in a list in a dropdown menu on my page.
Here's my code:

```
   <fieldset>
<legend> Selecteer uw Categorie </legend>

<label for   ="Categorie"> Categorie </label>
<select name ="Categorie" id="Categorie">
<datalist id ="Categorie">
<Option Value="Router">Router</option>
<Option Value="Switch">Switch</option>
<Option Value="Toestel">Toestel</option>
<Option Value="Basisstation">Basisstation</option>
<Option Value="Repeaters">Repeaters</option>
<Option Value= <?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","admin","inventarisdb");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Categorien");





while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<ul>";
  echo "<li>" . $row['Categorieen1'] . "</li>";

  echo "</ul>";
  }
echo "</table>";


mysqli_close($con);
?> 



</option>

</select>
</datalist>

</fieldset>
```

THis code works perfectly, It looks up the data i need and posts it in the dropdown list But it all gets posted in a single line..
I want it to be Listed underneath each other..
Please help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are all on a single line because you put your result in a single `<option>` tag.

try this:

```
<Option Value="Basisstation">Basisstation</option>
<Option Value="Repeaters">Repeaters</option>
    <?php
        $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","admin","inventarisdb");
        // Check connection
        if (mysqli_connect_errno())
        {
            echo "<option>Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error()."</option>";
        }

        $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Categorien");

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
             echo "<option>".$row['Categorieen1'] . "</option>";
        }

        mysqli_close($con);
    ?> 

</select>
</datalist>

</fieldset>
```

EDIT:

sorry for the mistake I forgot the second `echo` in the while loop XP!

Comment: Ty Sebastien for ur quick response.

After trying this code u posted I could no longer see my data in the dropdown list at all :S 

Any ideas? suggestions?

Comment: missing an echo in the while loop just fixed that sorry XD

Comment: Thank you Sebastian It looks perfect :) 

I'd vote u up but I am new and have no Rep :) 

Thank you again!

Comment: No problem! glad I was able to help